# Sorting mongodb aggregation by time, date and month

Tags: mongodb, sorting, datetime, aggregation

I've got an aggregation pipeline that sorts by the last 24 hours. The Json output generally looks something like the following:

```
[{"_id": {"day": 28, "hour": 23}, "count": 2},
```

However, because today is the first of the month, it got mixed up and the above json was the 'latest', while everything containing "day": 1, was sorted last.

I think I fixed it by adding 'month' into the query, but just to be sure is this the correct way of sorting my aggregation?

```
pipeline = [
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "mac": 1,
                "time": 1
            }
        },

        {"$match": {"time": {"$gt": timenow-timedelta(hours=24)}}},

        {"$group": {
            "_id": {
                'month': {"$month": {"date": '$time', "timezone": 'Africa/Johannesburg'}},
                'day': {"$dayOfMonth": {"date": '$time', "timezone": 'Africa/Johannesburg'}},
                'hour': {"$hour": {"date": '$time', "timezone": 'Africa/Johannesburg'}},
                'mac': {'_id': "$mac"}

            },
            "count": {"$sum": 1}

        }},

        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    'month':"$_id.month",
                    'day': "$_id.day",
                    'hour': "$_id.hour",
                },
                "count": {"$sum": 1}
            }
        },

        {"$sort": SON([("_id", -1)])}
    ]
```